# I have problems with getting rid of nautilus handling my desktop

Tags: wallpaper, nautilus

I have problems with getting rid of nautilus handling my desktop. I do not want to use it and my wallpapers look ugly because of it. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Can you help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to accept your own answer so that others can use it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer, I used this command:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

Comment: Would you accept your answer so other users can see it's solved?